# Connect boiler Wifi switcher

Tags: wiring, bathroom, water-heater, boiler

I want to connect boiler switcher, in the wall I have 4 wires, 2 live, neutral and earth, but on the wifi switcher it needs L(in) L1(out) N1(out) N(in) as shown in the pictures,

How can I connect it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that WEMO Wifi ?  ,read/ show datasheet .

Comment: This is Switcher touch

Comment: if you don't need N1, you don't have to use it. It looks like it can switch neutral too, or maybe the two Ns are just connected internally as a conveniences, like outlets having two terminals to chain them w/o wire nuts.

Comment: L/N to power source and L1/N1 to boiler